# Python - Download file from AWS S3 for the current date

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I am currently using the below python script to download data from AWS S3 to my local. Only problem I have is when I run this I have to manually enter the exact folder from where the files need to be downloaded. The S3 bucket I use creates a new folder for each day and I would like to download files from only the current day's folder. I tried creating a variable using the system date and tried to pass that in the bucket list variable but the script did nothing neither did it throw an error. Could anyone help me with this.

```
import boto, os
import datetime
from os import path

current_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


LOCAL_PATH = '/Users/user/Desktop/rep'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'ACCESS'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'SECRET'
bucket_name = 'bucket'

# connect to the bucket
conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)


# go through the list of files
bucket_list = bucket.list(prefix='Nation/State/City/2018-05-01')
#bucket_list = bucket.list(prefix='Nation/State/City/current_date')

#bucket_list = bucket.list()
for l in bucket_list:
  keyString = str(l.key)
  d = LOCAL_PATH + keyString
  try:
    l.get_contents_to_filename(d)
  except OSError:
  # check if dir exists
    if not os.path.exists(d):
    os.makedirs(d)
```

Thanks..

Comment: Also, be careful how you define "current date". This is based on the timezone, as to when the next day begins. For example, the current date in Australia is, for several hours, later than the current date in the USA. By default, Amazon EC2 instances operates on the UTC timezone, you might you might need to adjust it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python code is wrong for what you want.

The error is here:

```
bucket_list = bucket.list(prefix='Nation/State/City/current_date')
```

In this context, `current_data` is just a string containing the words `current_data`. To fix it you should change the line above to:

```
bucket_list = bucket.list(prefix='Nation/State/City/{}'.format(current_date))
```

This line will pick the value of `current_date` variable and set it in your prefix string, replacing the `{}`.

I would also recommend you to check this link:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3.